# Why am I throwing an exception on XElement.Load(...)?

Tags: c#

I am working my way through an instructional video. This should be simple code to execute and show a simple XML is listed below. ON the video you can see that the code works great and shows the XML in one of the simple DOS boxes.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLPROC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = XElement.Load("acct.xml");
            var qry = from ele in doc.Elements("acc")
                      select ele;

            foreach (var ele in qry)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account --> " + ele);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(">>>>>> Name Space Section <<<<<<");

            var doc2 = XElement.Load("acct2.xml");
            var qry2 = from ele in doc2.Elements("{urn:accounting}accounts")
                       select ele;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accounts>
  <acc name="AC1">100</account>
  <acc name="AC2">200</account>
  <acc name="AC3">300</account>
  <acc name="AC4">400</account>
  <acc name="AC5">500</account>
  <acc name="AC6">600</account>
  <acc name="AC7">700</account>
  <acc name="AC8">800</account>
  <acc name="AC9">900</account>
</accounts>
```

XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accounts xmlns="urn:accounting">
  <acc name="AC1">100</account>
  <acc name="AC2">200</account>
  <acc name="AC3">300</account>
  <acc name="AC4">400</account>
  <acc name="AC5">500</account>
  <acc name="AC6">600</account>
  <acc name="AC7">700</account>
  <acc name="AC8">800</account>
  <acc name="AC9">900</account>
</accounts>
```

---New Working XML---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accounts>
  <acc name="">100</acc>
  <acc name="">200</acc>
  <acc name="">300</acc>
  <acc name="">400</acc>
  <acc name="">500</acc>
  <acc name="">600</acc>
  <acc name="">700</acc>
  <acc name="">800</acc>
  <acc name="">900</acc>
</accounts>

-------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<accounts xmlns="urn:accounting">
  <acc name="">100</acc>
  <acc name="">200</acc>
  <acc name="">300</acc>
  <acc name="">400</acc>
  <acc name="">500</acc>
  <acc name="">600</acc>
  <acc name="">700</acc>
  <acc name="">800</acc>
  <acc name="">900</acc>
</accounts>

-------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bad-accounts>
  <acc name="">9</acc>
</bad-accounts>
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: it looks like you have a spurious `"` around the encoding assignment that is malforming your xml.

Comment: You can have access denied/file does not exist/invalid xml format

Comment: Could not find file '\\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XMLPROC\XMLPROC\bin\Debug\Accounts.xml'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the code gives me the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: System does not support 'utf-8 ?' encoding. Line 1, position 31.

This suggests that something is wrong with your XML format, specifically in the encoding. Looking at your encoding tag, you can notice that your encoding should actually be set with `encoding="utf-8"` but you are also including the  `?` from the XML tag closing.

So fix your encoding in both of the XML documents like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""utf-8" ?>
```

Now running your code again causes another error to occur:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: The 'acc' start tag on line 4 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'account'. Line 4, position 24.

This means that your tags must be invalid. Looking at your account tags, you see that you open with `<acc name="">` and try to close with `</account>`. These must be consistent. So fix each line like so:

```
<acc name="">value</acc>
```

This will allow you to build and run your program successfully, giving you the expected output.

If your exception now is that the file cannot be found, you need to change the path in your program (if using Visual Studio) to something like:

```
var doc = XElement.Load("../../acct.xml");
```

...which is a relative path to the base folder where the XML file likely sits. Adjust this as needed, or give it a full path to the file.